# how to send and show html table cell value to checkbox

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner with JavaScript; I want clicking on one row in html table, to send the row fields (cells) to page tags. For tags other than checkbox, it puts the correct value in the corresponding tag, but this code does not work only for the checkbox.html table filled from database table.

html code :

```
 3 tags office_id,caption,top_office_id

 <input type="checkbox" id="status" class="form-check-input">
```

and JavaScript code:

```
 <script>
   
         function addRowHandlers() {
            var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var currentRow = table.rows[i];
                var createClickHandler = function(row) {
                return function() {
                    var cell1 = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];var id = cell1.innerHTML;
                    var cell2 = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];var caption = cell2.innerHTML;
                    var cell3 = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[2];var top_id = cell3.innerHTML;
                    var cell4 = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[3];var status = cell4.innerHTML;
                    
                    document.getElementById("office_id").value=id;
                    document.getElementById("caption").value=caption;
                    document.getElementById("top_office_id").value=top_id;
                    if (status===1){
                        alert(status);
                        document.getElementById("status").checked=true;
                    }
                    else{
                        alert(status);
                        document.getElementById("status").checked=false;
                    }
                };
              };
              currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
            }
          }
          window.onload = addRowHandlers();
    </script>
```

I should also add that alerts work correctly and return the value of the table field correctly.

The first alert displays the value 1 depending on the selected line, and the second one displays the value zero.

Actually, my problem is to set the checkbox status (unchecked and checked) with zero and one values.

How can I set the checkbox values?

Comment: I don't get it 100%. My understanding: When you click on a row in the table, you want the values from the table inserted into a form with input elements that correspond to the table columns? Can you add to your question what the table might look like and also add the form.

Comment: You need to post enough HTML that we can see the problem. You want the state (checked/unchecked) of the checkbox elements to be set according to the `1`/`0` of a selected line? But you haven't shown any "lines" with `1` or `0`?

Comment: when i select table row,i get the status value 0 or 1, i want to display this value(0 or 1) on the checkbox by checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the cell content into a number and then use `!!` in front of the number to turn it into a boolean. The boolean can be used as the value of `checked` on the input check box.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let form = document.forms.form01;
  let row = e.target.closest('tr');
  if (row) {
    row.closest('table')
      .querySelectorAll('.selected')
      .forEach(elm => elm.classList.remove('selected'));
    row.classList.add('selected');
    let status = row.querySelector('td[data-name="status"]');
    form.status.checked = !!parseInt(status.textContent);
  }
});
```

```css
tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr.selected {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input type="checkbox" name="status" class="form-check-input">
</form>

<table id="table01">
  <tr>
    <td data-name="caption">Item 1</td>
    <td data-name="status">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-name="caption">Item 2</td>
    <td data-name="status">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-name="caption">Item 3</td>
    <td data-name="status">1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: chrwahl Thank you very much , it took me a lot of time